# Android Flyme OS custom notification icon (not system app)

Tags: android, notifications, icons, android-notifications

I have Flyme 5.1.6.0 G OS (not rooted) on my Meizu M2 note.

When I'm trying to create new notification in my android app with `new NotificationCompat.Builder` I do:

```
.setSmallIcon(icon_small)
.setLargeIcon(largeIcon)
```

And other methods, but icon in status bar is not what I've set.

Most notifications (including other apps) just get "speech bubble" icon.

BUT! There are at least two exceptions:

1. Google Chrome app
2. VK (social network) app

Both of them, just regular apps (not system apps), still can set their custom icons as shown on picture below:

[image: flyme os custom notification icon]

1) speech bubble icon (most apps)

2) custom VK icon (new message)

3) custom Chrome icon (close all incognito tabs)

So, that's why I think it is possible to set custom icon for notification for Flyme OS. Am I wrong?

If not, how can I do the same thing? How can VK and Chrome set their custom icons?

Comment: have the same problem! Trying to find solution in Telegram source code - it also has normal custom icon. We'll try to figure it out, прорвёмся! )